# Is there any package in node js that can connect to OPC-DA server?

Tags: node.js, opc-da

I want to create an OPC-DA client that can read OPC-DA servers in node js. I did not find enough resources to achieve this. Someone, please help me?

Comment: Did you find any working solution since?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library on npm -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-opc-da

From the docs:

> This library implements the OPC-DA specifications and allows to communicate with OPC Servers, relying on the node-dcom library for DCOM/DCE-RPC for protocol implementation. Currently this lib support browsing calls and synchronous reads. The code overall structure was heavly based on Utgard.

Just run `npm install node-opc-da` with your desired flags.